# Does time complexity of Hashmap get() and put() operation is O(1) at all time

Tags: hashmap, time-complexity, hashcode

Scenario :- All 12 elements got stored in hash map in one bucket itself due to bad hashcode implementation.

Does complexity will remain O(1) for get and put?
if not then
What is best way to achieve O(1) ? or in what scenario hashmap gives O(1) time complexity ?